# When Running Koa Server Locally Request IP Address is ::1

Tags: koa

I am running a Koa server locally and when I log the IP of an incoming request the value shows up as ::1, which is the IP address of the local server.  How do I get it to log the IP address of the user that made the request?

I am trying to get the user's IP like this:

`app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
     console.log(ctx.request.ip);
    });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you got `::1` then this is literally the IP address of the HTTP client that made the request. `::1` is the localhost address when using ipv6.

If you make the request from somewhere else, the ip will be different.